# Printing Google Apps Script Template in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I have a form that is submitted to a Google Apps Script for processing.  If the data is acceptable, a confirmation page is generated and displayed to the user:

```
function doGet() {
  var conf = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Confirmation.html');
  return conf.evaluate();
}
```

If I try to print this page with Chrome 26's print dialog I get a blank page with the header and footer on paper and in the preview.  However, it prints fine in Chrome using the system's print dialog and without problems in Firefox 20 and IE 9.

Any idea if there's something I can do to address this other than instruct Chrome users to print with the system dialog?

--Dave

Comment: +1!  I'm having the same problem.  Except, I'm on a Mac, and it doesn't print fine in Chrome or Safari.  It only shows maybe the top 1/3rd of my page then the rest is blank.

Comment: Email the confirmation to the user?

Answer (score 2):

GAS functionality is inside of an iframe this seems to break the printing for Chrome/Safari (webkit) browsers. For in-house apps you can give people a chrome bookmarklet that will allow printing.

```
javascript:document.body.innerHTML=window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML; setTimeout(window.print, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Random guess. Wrap it in a `<pre>` tag to strip any styling or code interpretation?